# How to reassign an element of a list that is in another list as variable?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to reassign an element in a list stored in a variable which is stored/called by another list, but I don't know how. Here are my lists:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]

listOfLists = [list1, list2]
```

So for example I want to change the value of the third element of the first list, I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
listOfLists[0][2]
```

I heard that you need to "travel all the list" with `for` - How it would be with this way?.

Comment: What you posted will work fine. You just need to actually assign something. Eg `listOfLists[0][2] = 99`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `=` operator to assign a new value.

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3]
>>> list2 = [4,5,6]
>>>
>>> listOfLists = [list1, list2]
>>> listOfLists[0][2] = 42
>>> listOfLists
[[1, 2, 42], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Note that the third element of the first list is now `42`.